# Aurelius Titan and Elasticsearch CONTAINS_REGEX not giving results

Tags: regex, indexing, elasticsearch, titan

I have a basic Titan instance running on Cassandra with elastic search for full-text indexing (se below for setup).

Elastic search index does not appear to return correctly when using `CONTAINS_REGEX` when the string parameter does not contain any sepertors like whitespace or `.`.

Example:

```
g.V().has('name', "somename") //This exist
==> v[123456] 
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, ".*somename.*") //This does not find the vertex.
==> null
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, ".*omenam.*") //Nor does this..
==> null
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, "somename") //Or this..
==> null
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, "^somename$") //String start + end does not work.
==> null

g.V().has('name', "somename.two") //If the name has a separator in it, then CONTAINS_REGEX works as expected
==> v[23456]
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, ".*somename.*")
==> v[23456]
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, ".*omenam.*")
==> v[23456]
g.V().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, "somename\\.two")
==> v[23456]

//Changing to the new syntax also does not work as expected.
g.query().has('name', CONTAINS_REGEX, ".*somename.*").vertices()
```

So, as you can see, `CONTAINS_REGEX` does not appear to behave correctly when the string does not contain any whitespace or other separators. This has worked on previous versions (0.4.X). Maybe something has changed that I am not aware of, and this should be done differently now. I was not able to find anything in the docs however. It could also be that there are some settings in either titan or ES I have not set up correctly, but again, I could not find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I am inserting the names like this:

```
def get_or_create_name(g, name)
{
    nv = g.V('name', name);
    if(!nv.hasNext())
    {
        ret = g.addVertexWithLabel('name');
        ElementHelper.setProperties(ret, 'name', name);
    }
    else
    {
        ret = nv.next();
    }
    ret
}
```

---

Using:

- Titan 0.5.2
- Debian 7.6
- Java `java version "1.7.0_65", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-5~deb7u1), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)`

Indexing part of db schema:

```
name_label = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("name").make()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).make()

name_uniqueness = mgmt.buildIndex("name_uniqueness",Vertex.class).addKey(name).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(name_uniqueness, ConsistencyModifier.DEFAULT); //Not sure if this is needed

mgmt.buildIndex('name_index',Vertex.class).addKey(name,Mapping.TEXT.getParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search")
```

**Small note**: I am aware that I could use `Mapping.STRING.getParameter()` in stead of `TEXT`, and then use  `g.V().has('name', REGEX, ".*somename.*")`, but I was never able to get the string index to work at all. I am also aware `CONTAINS_REGEX` is intended for use on each word within a longer text, but again, I was never able to get the string version to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through error logs and testing lots of stuff I found that the issue was that some of the java-processes were running out of memory. Specifically Rexster.

What I did was increase the available memory and tweak the java options a bit.

Thus, in `bin/rexster.sh` I changed this line:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dtitan.logdir=$LOG_DIR"
```

To:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms128m -Xmx2g -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dtitan.logdir=$LOG_DIR"
```

And now everything seems to be working nicely! :)

To recap: The issue was that Rexster crashed between storing to cassandra and the initialization of the elasticsearch index because of lack of ram.